# Having trouble with PHP ob_start callback function in a class

Tags: php

I am having a little trouble with an `ob_start` callback function inside a class. While searching the web, I found out how to do it! So I got the syntax for that down, but I am having a new problem that I cannot find a solution to on google.

So I have a header class,
methods in the header class that are relative to this problem are as follows:

```
nameBlock()
callback($buffer)
startHeaders()
```

at the beginning of the startHeaders() method I call the ob_start()..

```
 ob_start(array($this, 'callback'));
```

Here is the callback method it is calling:

```
function callback($buffer){
    $buffer = str_replace("<!!>nameBlock<!!>", $this->nameBlock(), $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
```

For a reason I don't know, it is not seeing it's own methods with the "$this->".

Answer (score -1):

You might try this instead.

```
ob_start(function($buffer) use ($this) {
    // code here....
});
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php that first param is supposed to be callable, not an array.

Comment: If used in the correct context (inside a method of a class that contains a method named `callback`), `array($this, 'callback')` **is** a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: That didn't work inside the class, I attempted and got an error, Fatal error: Cannot use $this as lexical variable in /.../header.php on line 147. Though as axiac mentioned, arrays are accepted from inside the class. I got the array help from [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php#40643).

Comment: I looked at that link and it looks like the array needs to accept `array('className', 'callBackMethodName')` I also did further reading and that the lambda should already have `$this` accessible from within a class assuming PHP5.4. If you use what I have but remove the `use ($this)` part it'll work. But at least imo this is more clear than array.

Comment: Actually moving to PHP 7, not that this has anything to do with the transition, just something that needed improving. Anyways i tried without the use ($this) and it did work, however I prefer the array call, I think it just looks cleaner having it's own method. Thanks however :).

Answer (score -1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I figured out the problem while typing the question.

The method:

```
nameBlock()
```

was printing out the content

```
print "X";
```

when it should have been returning it.

```
return "X";
```